# How to average data using latest timestamp record and interval?

Tags: mysql, arduino

I have 2 arduino devices that send sms (Humidity, temperature and rainfall) to my broadband stick, I also have a C# application that saves the data inside the text to my sql database, the problem is how can I average the inputs `humidity`, `temperature` and `rainfall` from both devices with 1 minute interval on my `time` field which is currently `Timestamp(3)` ?

this is not working but this is how I think it would work.

`Select AVG(humidity) as humidity WHERE time BETWEEN (LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP) interval = 1 min?`

Comment: Do you realize that most of your question is noise? I mean, we don't need to know the entire set up - this is clearly an sql question - so why should we care about anything other then what does the actual data in the database look like and what is the desired results?

Comment: is `LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP` standard mysql ? I've never seen it before

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nCFQqdo here is the database, what I want to do is to average the data with 1 min intervals using their timestamp.

Comment: @apokryfos last input timestamp is just my words to explain the latest input in the timestamp table, sorry.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

i guess you are looking for something like this:

```
Select AVG(humidity) as humidity WHERE time BETWEEN (LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP) AND DATE_SUB((LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Explanation:

```
DATE_SUB((LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Your current timestamp `(LAST INPUT TIMESTAMP)` will be substracted by a interval `INTERVAL 1 MINUTE`

**Edit based on your comment:**

Do a subselect to get the last timestamp like:

```
SELECT AVG(humidity) as humidity
FROM table
WHERE time BETWEEN (SELECT TOP 1 timestamp FROM table ORDER by timestamp DESC) 
    AND DATE_SUB((SELECT TOP 1 timestamp FROM table ORDER by timestamp DESC), INTERVAL 1 MINUTE)
```

Comment: hello sir, the `last input timestamp` is just my expression to say the latest input data on timestamp table i'm so sorry for misdirecting everyone.

Comment: added an answer based on you comment

Comment: I would try this one I'll send you the result later thank you very much sir!